# PuTTY - Error: "Software caused connection abort"

Tags: ssh, putty

I have a problem with my Raspberry Pi 3. When I want to connect to my Raspi, after a few attempts it works, but after while (like 1 minute) it says this error: "Software caused connection abort". I have already added IPQoS cs0 cs0
in SSH config but it didn't work. Any idea how to fix it, please?

Comment: You may also want to read this http://superuser.com/questions/294824/putty-network-error-software-caused-connection-abort

Answer (score 1):

## Try This

I added this to the end of my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file on my raspberry pi, and it seems to have helped keep my connections stable.  I don't remember exactly what it does, but it may help you.

```
# Added to keep sessions up
# Disabled TCPKeepAlive because it was frustrating
# Send an alive message 30 times before judging the connection inactive and closing it
ClientAliveCountMax 30
# Send the alive messages every 30 seconds
ClientAliveInterval 30
# This should total to 30x30 seconds = 15 minutes before inactive sessions are closed
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice but it didn't work. :(